# log every method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Instead of having to create a custom logger for TRACE, e.g. following what methods were called and what classes were instantiated, is there an easy way to make all methods under a class log themselves? This is for a node.js application.

```
class MyClass

  constructor: () ->
    console.log 'MyClass:constructor'

  doThat: () ->
    console.log 'MyClass:doThat'

exports.MyClass = MyClass

myClass = new MyClass()
myClass.doThat()
```

If I had my way, you'd see **4** log messages instead of 2 (thus having to write less code to trace what's happening).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently needed to implement something like this to trace some complicated OO-recursive stuff. Basically, i wanted to make a method "traceable" without polluting it too much; so maybe the solution could be applied here too.

First, add a function that makes other functions traceable:

```
Function::trace = do ->
  makeTracing = (ctorName, fnName, fn) ->
    (args...) ->
      console.log "#{ctorName}:#{fnName}"
      fn.apply @, args
  (arg) ->
    for own name, fn of arg 
      @prototype[name] = makeTracing @name, name, fn
```

Then, to use it, just add a `@trace` before each method you want to trace:

```
class MyClass
  @trace methodA: ->
    @methodB 42

  @trace methodB: ->
    console.log "method b called with #{n}"
```

Or add @trace only once and then indent all the traceable methods one more level:

```
class MyClass
  @trace 
    methodA: ->
      @methodB 42

    methodB: (n) ->
      console.log "method b called with #{n}"
```

As you can see `trace` is kind of abusing CoffeeScript's syntax. `method: -> 'foo'` inside a `class MyClass` is interpreted a method definition. But `@trace method: -> 'foo'` is interpreted a calling the `trace` function of `MyClass` (which is a `Function` instance, to which we've added the `trace` function) passing it a literal object with one `method` key. In JavaScript it would be something like `this.trace({method: function() {return 'foo';}})`.

The `trace` function will just take that object and iterate it's keys (the method names) and values (the methods) and add functions to the `MyClass` prototype that log their calls and in turn call the original methods.

Anyway, the output of `(new MyClass).methodA()` will be:

```
MyClass:methodA
MyClass:methodB
method b called with 42
```

This solution doesn't work for constructors though, as they are not just normal methods.

You can get quite fancy with this. You can also log the arguments passed to each method, the return value, and even add indentation for nested calls if you so desire (the resulting traces can then be very helpful if you need to debug a complex problem =D).

---

Update: as a more interesting example, here's a mini-version of the typical composite pattern example, geometrical figures and groups of figures: http://jsfiddle.net/2YuE7/ with a more interesting tracing function. All figures understand the `move` method. If we have this composite figure and call `move` on it:

```
f = new Composite [
  new Rectangle 5, 10, 3, 4
  new Composite [
    new Circle 0, 0, 2
    new Circle 0, 0, 4
    new Circle 0, 0, 6
  ]
]

f.move 2, 3
```

The trace output is:

```
(Composite[Rectangle[5,10,3,4],Composite[Circle[0,0,2],Circle[0,0,4],Circle[0,0,6]]]).move(2, 3)
| (Rectangle[5,10,3,4]).move(2, 3)
| -> Rectangle[7,13,3,4]
| (Composite[Circle[0,0,2],Circle[0,0,4],Circle[0,0,6]]).move(2, 3)
| | (Circle[0,0,2]).move(2, 3)
| | -> Circle[2,3,2]
| | (Circle[0,0,4]).move(2, 3)
| | -> Circle[2,3,4]
| | (Circle[0,0,6]).move(2, 3)
| | -> Circle[2,3,6]
| -> Composite[Circle[2,3,2],Circle[2,3,4],Circle[2,3,6]]
-> Composite[Rectangle[7,13,3,4],Composite[Circle[2,3,2],Circle[2,3,4],Circle[2,3,6]]]
```

Comment: This is very cool. The ability to log arguments was also something I was thinking about. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankLoVecchio Cool. I updated the answer with an example that logs parameters, return values and indents the logs depending on the recursion level =D

Comment: This is going to be a highly useful StackOverflow question :)

Comment: Do you potentially know why this would break a Backbone Marionette trigger? https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/issues/222

Comment: @FrankLoVecchio That was unexpected! Anyways, it's no Marionette's fault. The CoffeeScript compiler that JSFiddle is using is an old version (1.1.2) and it's is messing up the syntax there (i said it was kind of abusive on the syntax hehe). You can see that comparing the generated JS code in your second link (Show JS in JSFiddle) and what is generated in [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#try:) with the same CS input. But don't worry, if you use the latest CS version it [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/xzeHb/155/) just fine =D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so something with plain old javascript, I created a service to which you can pass an object which will return an object with the same API that logs each method. See the full example with the polyfill applied at http://jsfiddle.net/mcgraphix/pagkoLjb

The basic idea is:

```
var api = {
   notAMethod: "blah",
   foo: function() {
    console.log("in foo", arguments);
   },

   bar: function(arg) {
    this.foo(arg);
    return this.notAMethod;
   }
}; 

//wrap the api with a logging version
//to watch property changes and keep them in sync, you need the polyfill for Object.watch
//     from https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583

var createLogger = function(api) {
     var loggingApi = {};

            for (var prop in api) {
                if (typeof api[prop] !== 'function') {
                   loggingApi[prop] = api[prop]; 
                   loggingApi.watch(prop, function(prop, oldVal, newVal){
                       api[prop] = newVal
                       return newVal;
                   });


                } else {

                    loggingApi[prop] = function() {
                        console.log(prop + "() called with args: ", arguments);
                        var returnVal = api[prop].apply(api, arguments);
                         console.log(prop + "() returned: " + returnVal);
                        return returnVal;
                    }
                }
            }
      return loggingApi;
 };
 api.foo('Shhhh... don\'t log me') //no logging
 createLogger(api).foo(); //with logging
```